# How to get a single dimensional array from space and new line separated file in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io

I have an text file that contains data in following format

> ABC DEF GHI IJk
>
> LMN OPQ RST UVW
>
> XYZ ABC CDE EFH

Now I want to read that input in a single dimensional array as shown below:

```
string[] input = { ABC,DEF,GHI,IJK,LMN,OPQ,RST,UVW,XYZ,ABC,CDE,EFH}
```

Comment: What have you tried, what are you having trouble with? Try searching the web or this site for "C# read file", "C# split string".

Comment: @CodeCaster: I can do it using two loops...but I want an efficient way to do that...

Comment: Why do you think the loops aren't efficient? And please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "...";
string[] input = str.Split(' ').Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will deal with different types of whitespace and newline conventions.

```
 const char[] delimiters = new char[] {' ', '\n', '\r', '\f', '\t'};

 string rawInput = "ABC DEF GHI IJK\n\nLMN\tOPQ  RST UVW\n\r XYZ ABC CDE EFH";
 string[] input = rawInput.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```